# How to compare consecutive case sensitive words with awk in Linux?

Tags: linux, awk

```
awk '{
for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { 
    j = i + 1;
    if($i == $j) {
        print FNR " | " $0 " | " $i; 
    }
}
}' myfile
```

If `myfile` has these lines:

```
There is a storm storm outside .

My my car is red .
```

The output will be:

```
1 | There is a storm storm outside . | storm
```

How can I make the command to ignore case sensitivity and also display ?

```
2 | My my car is red . | my
```

Comment: In the for-loop the conditions should be `i < NF`! Otherwise `j = j + 1` will point to a non-existing element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use '**toupper**' to convert strings to uppercase

```
if(toupper($i) == toupper($j)) {
```